# libreoffice-fresh cannot find libGLEW.so.2.0 in Manjaro / Antergos

Tags: libreoffice, glew, manjaro

I cannot run libreoffice-fresh in Manjaro KDE (17.0.5) or in Antergos KDE (17.9).

It installs perfectly using `pacman`, but when I try running it I get the following error:

> /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin: error while loading shared
>   libraries: libGLEW.so.2.0: cannot open shared object file: No such
>   file or directory

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix it. I just created a symlink like so:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libGLEW.so /usr/lib/libGLEW.so.2.0
```